# Option value on form parsing value not text

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange, getelementbyid, selectedindex

I am trying to create a basic online form where depending on what is selected the background colour of a table is changed to the appropriate option value.

The problem I have is when the form is submitted the option value is being submitted rather than the text which is what I need.

Is there a way of modifying the onChange or perhaps a better way altogether ?

Thanks for your help.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Survey</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border="0" width="21%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="20">
<tr>
    <td id = "mycell"> 
<p style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px"> 
<select name="q11" <select onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0)
document.getElementById('mycell').bgColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="#FFFFFF">Choose a factor...    
<option value="#F6B23E">My Company – feeling positive about who I work for
<option value="#F58386">My Leaders – being inspired by my business leaders 
<option value="#EF3135">My Boss – mutual respect and understanding
<option value="#F58386">My Team – enjoying who I work with
<option value="#AD6AA3">My Job – enjoying what I do
<option value="#95CAA0">My Personal Growth – learning, development and prospects 
<option value="#4FA761">My Deal – satisfaction with pay and benefits 
<option value="#95CAA0">My Wellbeing – having a balanced life 
</select></td>
```

Comment: save the text in a hidden element onchange then retrieve that value in the backend

Comment: You have to get the text and save it to a `<input type="hidden">` inside your onchange function as well. The form will only pass `name` and `value` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to get the data present inside the **option** tag try using:

```
.text()
or
innerhtml
```

feature of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to cheat like this :

get the className rather than value

```
<select onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0)
document.getElementById('mycell').bgColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className">
```

And set the color into the className

```
<option value="My Company " class="#F6B23E">My Company – feeling positive about who I work for</option>
```

But not sure it is cross-brother, and above all, a good way to do, but it should work for you.